# Utilizar Includes no autoload do CodeIgniter é uma boa prática?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eu tenho um projeto que utiliza o autoload para carregar diversas bibliotecas, Helpers, usando diversos include_once. 
Como Inputs, Formulários etc.

Alguns são usados em vários controladores, outros nem tanto. Seria uma boa prática carregar todos no autoload ou é melhor carregar por demanda?
Sobrecarregaria o servidor caso isso seja feito no autoload?
Muito obrigado!

Comment: Minha dica: utilize a função `spl_autoload_register`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que não.

Basicamente o que o autoload faz é carregar a classe/funções pra instância do CodeIgniter.

Se por acaso eu tenho um helper que me auxilie com faturas, eu carrego ele apenas onde for utilizar. Entretanto, se eu uso uma classe de template engine na qual vou utilizar em todas as views, eu deixo ele carregado diretamente no autoload.

Uma alternativa é utilizar composer autoload.

Dê uma lida: [Auto-loading Resources - CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html)